# Can we consider the CLR as a Sandbox?

Tags: .net, clr

By definition a sandbox is an environnement where every aspect of security is controlled by the host .

am I wrong if I say that The CLR is a sort of sandbox for windows programs ?

Comment: A sandbox is about isolation not security.  They can be the same thing but that is not a requirement.

Comment: the CLR could considered a sandbox but it is pretty easy to get out of it if you are using the full CLR (pinvoke) and not something better contained like UWP or Silverlight.

Comment: what about Appdomains ? theu provide isolation are they sandboxes , what I want is a concret example of a sandbox .

Comment: Anything can be used as a sandbox. HttpClient can be considered a sandbox around webrequests versus using sockets. AppDomains can be used as layers of isolation within your application... but you can also bridge out of them as needed. You can even use threads, objects and functions as sandboxes.

Comment: It can *create* a sandbox.  You can explicitly forbid certain kind of code from executing.  The CLR itself is just a big chunk of C++ code, not a sandbox and not subject to sandbox restrictions, other than what the OS disallows.

Comment: Ok , what do you main by " certain kind of code " ?